# Im trying to Create a encryption program but i get errors at the start

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
// This portion works

    import java.util.Scanner;
      class test {
    private static Scanner inp;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input Password");
        int n = inp.nextInt();
        System.out.println(n);
        if(n!=234) {
            System.out.println("Denied Acess");

        } else { 
            System.out.print("Password Accepted");
        }
```

Program Errors below and outputs the following

```
java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match         valid=false]
[need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\,]
[decimal separator=\.][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=]
[negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q?\E][infinity string=\Q?\E]

/*Pseudocode:
Text: Input Text to Encrypt
            "User Input"
Text: "User input output for test pourposes"
*/
        Scanner enc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input Text to encrypt");
        System.out.println(enc);
      }
    }
```

Comment: You should only wrap a `System.in` once. You have an `inp` just keep using that.

Comment: BTW That's not an error. It's the expected output of this program. You printed out the `Scanner` object and that's what you should get so, can you clarify what you expected to happen?

Comment: i want it to out put the text inputted by the user but its not allowing an input

Comment: and how to i get another input point? thats what im trying to do

Comment: You used `inp.nextInt()` to get an `int` so you might try `inp.nextLine()` to get a line. The first line will be blank because it's the line after the number but if you ignore it, you can read text.

Comment: im just starting it out im just trying to get the input working atm

Comment: i want the section to be a new input point for an undefined amount of text,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    private static Scanner inp;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input Password: ");
        int n = inp.nextInt(); // For int
        System.out.println(n);

        if(n != 234)
        {
            System.out.println("Denied Access");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Password Accepted");
        }

        /* Scanner has already been initialized, don't create 
           a new one, use existing one, don't try and print the 
           Scanner because it is of type Scanner. */


        System.out.print("Input Text to encrypt: ");
        String m = inp.next(); // For String
        System.out.println(m);
    }
}
```

Please refer to this for explanation on Scanner class: http://www.javatpoint.com/Scanner-class

Comment: this worked :D thank you now how do i get it to show "password accepted" and "input text" to show on diffrent lines and not next to eachother

Comment: Mark as correct then please, and please don't forget to read that link.